# How pull text a little down in button

Tags: html, css

I have simple button with image and text, but text not align by image.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <img class="" style="min-width: 16px;min-height: 16px;width: 16px;height: 16px;" src="/Content/img/cart.png">
    <span>Buy</span> 
    <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
```

And screenshot

[image]

And jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e40sb9eg/

Comment: get jsfidle with your stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id to your text span like this...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
   <img class="" style="min-width: 16px;min-height: 16px;width: 16px;height: 16px;" src="/Content/img/cart.png">
   <span id="btn-text">Buy</span> 
   <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

In CSS, add

```
#btn-text {
    margin-top: 5px; /* Change this value if you want */
}
```

Comment: what if my button is big?

Comment: You can try `vertical-align: bottom;` or `margin-bottom: -5px;`

Comment: @Mediator: Can you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: @Mediator: Check now: http://jsfiddle.net/e40sb9eg/1/

Try changing the `margin-bottom` but let it be negative.

If you want, you can also change the dimensions of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to align text with image with `vertical-align` property:

```css
.btn > * {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <img class="" style="min-width: 16px;min-height: 16px;width: 16px;height: 16px;" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-free/64/cart-alt-20.png">
    <span>Buy</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```